# Sample node.js doing form handling and processing - in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, iot

I need a pointer or sample tutorial or some examples to form handling in Node.js.
I have a form.html which has 3 buttons "Forward", "Backward", "Stop" and they will have to call a process get and appropriately send messages to the backend component to take appropriate action.
My sample node.js that comes when I create the application is good, but it does not have form processing, so a link to some worked examples would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the express framework to process the form.

```
<form action="/processForm" method="POST">
  What's your name?: <input type="text" name="yourname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Forward">
</form>
```

node backend:

```
app.post('/processForm',function(req,res){
  var yourname=req.body.yourname;
  res.end("Hello " + yourname);
});
```

Great tutorials: 
https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/handle-get-post-request-express-4/
http://www.hacksparrow.com/form-handling-processing-in-express-js.html

Comment: Thanks Ram, Let me give it a try.

Comment: Ram, Followed your notes .. and I was able to get somethings going - Just acknowledging thanks.

Comment: Great. If my answer worked, I would appreciate it if you can accept it.

Comment: John - Thanks for the note - I just updated the answer. Newbie here.